# simplifying using Boolean Algebra.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was doing the following question. Using the following rules of boolean algebra:

```
         _
law 1: X+X=1


law 2: X.1=X


law 3:X.Y+X.Z = X.(Y+Z)
```

simplify:

```
    __  _   __ 
ABC+ABC+ABC+ABC
```

I have tried to simplify starting off with law 1, but I get stuck because the complements somewhat confuse me.

The bar meaning complement or 'not'

Could someone explain?

Comment: @rschwieb I edited, sorry for confusion.

Comment: The notation in the laws and the notation in the question are still completely different. If you think my solution below is answering the question you asked, I can attempt to make your post clear.

Comment: Are the second and third terms $\overline{A}\overline{B}C$ or are they $\overline{AB}C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is to reduce
$$
(\overline{A \& B} \& C) + (\overline{A} \& B \& C)+ (\overline{A \& B} \& C) +(A\& B \& C) 
$$

You can deduce from the laws that $X+X=X$, so this is clearly already

$$
=(\overline{A \& B} \& C) + (\overline{A} \& B \& C)+(A\& B \& C) 
$$
By law 3, then law 1, then law 2: $ (\overline{A} \& B \& C)+(A\& B \& C)=(\overline{A}+A)\&B\& C=1\&B\& C=B\&C $, so the original expression is now:

$$
=(\overline{A \& B} \& C)+B\&C 
$$

By [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demorgan%27s_Laws) $\overline{A \& B}=(\overline{A}+\overline{B})$, and you can deduce the rest from your laws:

$$
=(\overline{A} + \overline{B}) \& C+B \& C =(\overline{A} + \overline{B}+B) \& C 
$$

$$
=(\overline{A} + 1) \& C=1\&C=C 
$$

Comment: This is perfect Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ABC+A'B'C+A'BC+A'B'C

=ABC+A'B'C+A'BC

=ABC+(A'+B')C+A'BC

=ABC+A'C+B'C+A'BC

=BC(A+A')+A'C+B'C

=BC+AC+B'C

=C(B+B')+AC

=C+AC

=C(1+A)

=C

Comment: A bit of explanation in English words would be helpful for everyone concerned.

Answer (score 0):

=C(AB+A'B')+ A'C(B+B')
=C(1) + A'C(1)
=C + A'C
=C(1+A')
=C    according to (1+x=1)